# Swap integer in a string with equal distance

Tags: android, string, algorithm, kotlin

> Swap integer at equal distance in a string

for e.g   A1B2C  -> A2B1C, 4A5 -> 5A4 , Ab45 -> Ab45,

If an int is **equally distance** on both end it would replace

I want to achieve it with best time complexity. Kindly improve my code wherever required

```
fun swapIntAtEqualDistance(str: String):String{
    val charArray = str.toCharArray()
    val iteration = if(charArray.size % 2 == 0) charArray.size/2 -1 else charArray.size/2
    for(i in 0..iteration){
        val rightIndex = charArray.lastIndex - i
        val startChar = charArray[i]
        val endChar = charArray[rightIndex]

        if(startChar.isDigit() && endChar.isDigit()){
            val temp = charArray[i]
            charArray[i] = charArray[rightIndex]
            charArray[rightIndex] = temp
        }
    }
    return charArray.toList().toString()
}
```

Comment: Why does no replacement occur for `Ab45` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because if you have 5 chars string you have to replace 0 position with 4 position, 1 with 3 position and 2 is same from both sides.

Comment: You are already checking only half of the array and swapping only when required (even though none of that really affects the big O time complexity, but it does reduce the amount of work). Is there anything else that you want to optimize? What exactly did you get stuck on?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Code Review. Anyway, since it is *O(n)* you can’t improve time complexity. Maybe you can make some micro-optimizations.